# Como verificar se um email foi enviado com sucesso?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email

Estou a tentar verificar se um email enviado a partir da minha aplicação é enviado com sucesso, pretendendo saber se o destinatário o recebe ou não (caixa de correio cheia, email inválido, por ai). Pelo que pesquisei existe `deliverynotificationoptions` que a partida me devia dar informações se o email foi enviado ou não.

```
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
```

De seguida tento enviar o email:

```
try
{
   SmtpCliente.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return ex.Message;
}
```

A verdade é que não estou a conseguir obter essa informação... Existe outra forma de obter esta informação, ou é mesmo impossível?

Comment: Olá. Um detalhe, as `DeliveryNotificationOptions` são flags. pelo que para as utilizar deve fazer `.OnFailure | .OnSuccess | .Delay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após a execucação do método `SmtpCliente.Send(mail);`, caso nenhuma exceção ocorra, isso significa que o e-mail foi enviado ao servidor SMTP. Após isso, não há garantias de que seu e-mail será entregue ao destinatário. Veja esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342456/how-to-check-if-the-mail-has-been-sent-sucessfully) que stackoverflow em inglês.

Note que mesmo o evento `message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;` não garante que sua mensagem será recebida pois o destinatário pode não lhe enviar um e-mail de resposta e ter recebido sua mensagem.

Comment: Mas mesmo que eu use um email inventado (tipo asd@asdxcx.pt), ele dá nunca falha na execução do `SmtpCliente.Send(mail);` No try catch que tenho, ele nunca entra no catch caso o email seja inventado

Comment: O protocolo SMTP infelizmente não verifica se seu destinatário existe. Eu entendo sua frustração, já que infelizmente consegue-se garantir muito pouco em relação ao envio de e-mails.

Comment: Eu estou a usar o mailjet para fazer o envio, e consigo verificar sempre o status do email pelo browser... Mas estou a ver que não consigo ir buscar esses dados por código

Comment: Veja que o mailjet possui uma API que possibilita a chamada de funções via REST: https://www.mailjet.com/docs/api

Comment: O link a seguir mostra um método para recuperação de uma lista de emails enviados. Mesmo assim, não se garante que os mesmos foram recebidos. https://www.mailjet.com/docs/api/report/emailsent

Comment: Exacto, pena estar em php :/ vou ver se consigo replicar o código para C#

Comment: Apesar de estar em PHP, você consegue fazer chamadas REST em C#. Contudo, concordo que seria mais simples se a API estivesse em C#.